# RTCEAGLVideoView of GoogleWebRTC did not display remote video while remote audio is fine

Tags: ios, webrtc

I am making a video call feature in Swift, with GoogleWebRTC (1.1.27828) pod.
Code runs on iPhone 7 Plus with iOS 13.4, and also on an iPad Air 3 with iPad OS 13.4, same issue. Xcode is Version 11.4 (11E146). mac OS is 10.15.4（19E266).

Everything seem fine, and remote audio is ok too; but the remote view is still black.
below is the event handler in question:

```
    func peerConnection(_ peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection, didAdd stream: RTCMediaStream) {

        let ac = stream.audioTracks.count
        let vc = stream.videoTracks.count
        print("\(#function) peer.onaddstream(): # of tracks: A=\(ac) V=\(vc)")

        self.remoteVideoTrack = stream.videoTracks.first
        print("track: \(String(describing: self.remoteVideoTrack)), view: \(self.remoteVideoView)")

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.remoteVideoTrack!.add(self.remoteVideoView)
        }   
    }
```

the console log is like below.

```
peerConnection(_:didAdd:) peer.onaddstream(): # of tracks: A=1 V=1
track: Optional(RTCMediaStreamTrack:
video
7879E59A-6313-497B-821F-7D22AC5EF35A
enabled
Live), view: <RTCEAGLVideoView: 0x105d74fc0; frame = (138.667 0; 67.3333 100); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x28023a220>>
```

And no exception occurs.

So why the view is still black while audio is okay? 
Can anyone help? Thank you very much!

Comment: did you found any solution?

Comment: @guru sadly not yet ..

Comment: Any solution worked for you @losiu?

Comment: @SajidZeb still no.. :(